# Search Sublime Text 3 for files that don't contain a specific string

Tags: regex, search, sublimetext3, sublimetext

Is it possible to carry out a search in Sublime Text 3 for files that don't contain the following string: 'include/config.php'?

This doesn't work:

```
(?!include/config.php)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't use an unanchored lookahead, it will be looking anywhere inside a text.

Since `^` matches a beginning of a line, you'd rather use `\A` anchor that matches the beginning of the whole text.

Also, you need to be able to check across newlines and text, thus, you need to enable a DOTALL mode with `(?s)`  and use `.*` inside the lookahead.

Also, to make sure we match whole words, use `\b` (word boundaries). And do not forget to escape the dot to match a literal dot.

Use

```
(?s)\A(?!.*\binclude/config\.php\b)
```

Comment: Thanks very much.  I also wanted to know how to do this but never found an example that I understood until now.

Comment: Amazing.  Great answer.  Worked perfectly.